# laravel-poc-CVE-2018-15133

Tags: exploit, laravel

I want to test laravel exploit POC based on https://github.com/kozmic/laravel-poc-CVE-2018-15133/

I did docker steps to reach laravel home page on `localhost:8000` then I got API key and simply I put APIKEY in PHP command to find header.

When I sent POST request with exploit via curl there is not the expected response from the RCE.

Please look at below screenshot, I followed the ReadME steps certainly.

[image]

Is there any bug in the source code? or there is some issue in my usage? 
Guide me please.

Comment: The screenshot clearly shows a response. And furthermore, perhaps including your API key in a public question is not the best idea.

Comment: This is not  response to code execution and this is html response.
In github source code mentiond after doing final steps, it returned "uname -a" execution response.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text. Copy/paste and use the code formatting tool

Comment: I'm not sure that we can help you. We are not going to review the code and all we can do is to check that you ran all the commands properly. This is a question for the PoC dev.

Comment: please explain a bit this vulnerability. don't post screenshots with text. format your code. write what you have done and what didn't work. running `exploit.exe` and saying "it didn't work, so help me" is not really great. you need to specify where did you stuck and gives some results.